# Does ruby stop evaluating if statements when first condition is false?

Tags: ruby

Does ruby stop evaluating if statements when first condition is false? I constantly get `` undefined method `ready' for nil:NilClass> `` if `song = nil`.

```
    if !song.nil? && song.ready && !song.has_been_downloaded_by(event.author)
      song.send_to_user(event.author)
      nil
    elsif !song.ready
      "The song is not ready yet. Try again once it is."
    elsif song.has_been_downloaded_by(event.author)
      "Yo, check your private messages, I've already sent you the song."
    else
      'Song with such index does not exist.'
    end
```

Comment: It does, the error message comes from your first `elsif`.

Comment: @Stefan you're right, thanks

Comment: Always take a look at the error's line number ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Ruby, and most other programming languages use short circuiting boolean expressions. Meaning any expression of the form `false && puts("hi")` will not run the right side of the expression `puts("hi")`. This goes for `if` conditions as well, anything with `&&` really.

This is specially important to know because you always want to put faster or cheaper expressions/functions on the left side and more expensive expressions on the right side of a `&&` operator.

Consider this

```
puts "hi" if expensive_method() && some_value
```

In the above example `expensive_method` will always run. But what if `some_value` is sometimes false? This would be more efficient:

```
puts "hi" if some_value && expensive_method()
```

Taking advantage of the possibility that `some_value` might sometimes be false, we spare ourselves from having to evaluate `expensive_method` in those cases.

In short, take advantage of boolean expression short circuiting.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation

Comment: I think you forgot an `if` in `puts "hi" some_value && expensive_method()`

Answer (score 4):

For the exception to occur in the first line:

```
if !song.nil? && song.ready && !song.has_been_downloaded_by(event.author)
```

when `song.ready` is executed, `song` must equal `nil`, but to reach `song.ready`, `!song.nil?` must be true, meaning `song` is not `nil`, a contradiction. Therefore, we conclude that `song` must be `nil`, so the first `elsif` is executed:

```
elsif !song.ready
```

which is equivalent to

```
elsif !(nil.ready)
```

raising the exception.

More generally, error messages contain valuable information and deserve careful study. Yours would also identify the line where the exception occurred. The error message tells you that `song` is `nil` at that point. It therefore must have been `nil` in the first statement, so the first statement would have evaluated `nil`.

Consider putting your clause in a method and rewriting it as follows.

```
def process_song(song)
  return nil, "song is nil" if song.nil?
  return false, "The song is not ready yet. Try again once it is." unless song.ready
  return false, "Yo, check your private messages, I've already sent you the song." \
    if song.has_been_downloaded_by(event.author)
  song.send_to_user(event.author)
  true
end
```

to be called as follows.

```
outcome, msg = process_song(song)
```

Then, perhaps something like the following.

```
case outcome
when true
  ...
when false
  puts msg
  ...
when nil
  <raise exception with message that song is nil>
else
  <raise exception with message>
end
```

`msg` is `nil` when `outcome` is `true`. The first three lines of the method are called "guard clauses".

Answer (score 1):

The two other answers have already mentioned why you are getting the error. To fix this it is very simple, you just need to change the order of your `if` statement. Like so:

```
if song.nil? 
  'Song with such index does not exist.'
elsif song.ready && !song.has_been_downloaded_by(event.author)
  song.send_to_user(event.author)
  nil
elsif !song.ready
  "The song is not ready yet. Try again once it is."
elsif song.has_been_downloaded_by(event.author)
  "Yo, check your private messages, I've already sent you the song."
end
```

So now, you are checking whether `song == nil` in your first statement, and if that is `true`, you get the message `Song with such index does not exist.` Now, you can move onto the rest of your `elsif` without having to worry about `song` being `nil`.

Comment: You could move the first `elsif` to the end and make it a plain `else`. This would also separate the failure actions from the success action.